# How to "draw" touchable segmented rings, curves or arcs to build modern component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphics2d, curve

I want to implement a React Native component made up of segmented rings and arcs. It is difficult to explain, so the best thing is to show an image:

[image]

Each colored segment or arc can be pressed. I think that the key thing here is to create these arcs, but I don't know how to "draw" them.

Comment: One way is to draw the segments to a canvas, bind on `click`, compute which segment was clicked, and then fire another event based on that.

Comment: I think this is quite difficult to be implemented from scratch in RN (I've struggled to implement a custom "curvy" pie chart and after some weeks of research/work I've succeeded - by using react-native-svg and creating everything out of paths; but honestly it wasn't what I wanted only close to it). Anyway I strongly recommend you to take a look at victory pie charts (your image is similar to polar pie charts) and maybe you can use something from there